# How to dynamically interact with an AmCharts Map using Nuxt.js?

Tags: nuxt.js, amcharts, amcharts4

I would like to add an interactive map to my Nuxt.js website. I simply created a component that consists of the world map with AmCharts lib.
My goal is to change the color of some countries (France in my example) if a button is clicked. Here is what my file looks like:

```js
// components/Map.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <div id="chartdiv"/>
    <button @click="colorMe()">Click me!</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4maps from "@amcharts/amcharts4/maps";
import am4geodata_worldUltra from "@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata/worldUltra";

export default {
  methods: {
    colorMe() {
      worldPolygonSeries.getPolygonById("FR").fill = am4core.color("#f00");
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // Create map instance
    let map = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);
        
    // Set map definition
    map.geodata = am4geodata_worldUltra;
        
    // Set projection
    map.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();
    
    // Zoom control
    map.zoomControl = new am4maps.ZoomControl();
        
    // The world
    let worldPolygonSeries = map.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());    
    worldPolygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
  }      
}
</script>

<style scoped>
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
</style>
```

The error I get when I click the button is `worldPolygonSeries is not defined`. So I tried to create `map` and `worldPolygonSeries` directly inside the data part and to pass it as parameters but this isn't working...

Something like this:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      map: am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart),
      worldPolygonSeries: map.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries())
    }
  },
  methods: {
    colorMe(worldPolygonSeries) {
      worldPolygonSeries.getPolygonById("FR").fill = am4core.color("#f00");
    }
  },
  mounted(map, worldPolygonSeries) {        
    // Set map definition
    map.geodata = am4geodata_worldUltra;
        
    // Set projection
    map.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();
    
    // Zoom control
    map.zoomControl = new am4maps.ZoomControl();
        
    // The world
    worldPolygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
  }
}
```

So now the error I get is `Cannot set property 'geodata' of undefined`. Is someone has any idea of how I can manage my code to reach my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it!
I just change my variables to undefined on the data part, then I could access it from `mounted` and `methods`.

```js
// components/Map.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <div id="chartdiv" class="h-96"/>
    <button @click="colorMe(worldPolygonSeries)">Click me!</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
import * as am4maps from "@amcharts/amcharts4/maps";
import am4geodata_worldUltra from "@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata/worldUltra";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      map: undefined,
      worldPolygonSeries: undefined
    }
  },
  methods: {
    colorMe(worldPolygonSeries) {
      worldPolygonSeries.getPolygonById("FR").fill = am4core.color("#f00");
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // Create map instance
    this.map = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);
        
    // Set map definition
    this.map.geodata = am4geodata_worldUltra;
        
    // Set projection
    this.map.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();
    
    // Zoom control
    this.map.zoomControl = new am4maps.ZoomControl();
        
    // The world
    this.worldPolygonSeries = this.map.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());    
    this.worldPolygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
  }
}     
</script>

<style scoped>
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
</style>
```

Thanks for your help Iman ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `mounted()` doesn't take arguments, instead, use `this` for accessing `data`:

```
 mounted() {        
     // Set map definition
    this.map.geodata = am4geodata_worldUltra;
    
    // Set projection
    this.map.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();

    // Zoom control
    this.map.zoomControl = new am4maps.ZoomControl();
    
    // The world
    this.worldPolygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
}
```

Comment: Good to know, thanks! Unfortunately, I still get the same errors `map is not defined` and `Cannot set property 'geodata' of undefined` on my console log...

Comment: Could you please try to initiate `this.map` in the `mounted()` like: `this.map = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart)` . You error means `this.map` is undefined.